# JavaFx can not continually zoom out

Tags: javafx

I encountered some strange problem with JavaFX.
The use case is: I want to zoom out a swatch.
I implemented a Scroll event handler, like this:

```
private void handleSwatchScrollAction(ScrollEvent se){
        if(se.getEventType().equals(ScrollEvent.SCROLL)){
            System.out.println("Enter into handleSwatchScrollAction ");
           
            //The following two lines just want to calculate a ration to scale
            double diff = (se.getDeltaY() / 40) * 2;
            double diffFactor = diff / 2 / this.fxDial.getRadius() + 1;
            System.out.println("diffFactor is: " + diffFactor);
           
            //The following lines is to set scale
            this.fxSwatch.setScaleX(diffFactor);
            this.fxSwatch.setScaleY(diffFactor);
        }
        System.out.println("finish handleDialScrollAction");
    }
```

Problem is, when I use scroll to zoom out, the first time zoom out operation works well.
But from the second time, from the view there is no change.
The log looks right, but just no change to display, everything the same as before.

for example, the log is always like this when I continually do zoom out operation(scroll up), no matter the first time or after that:

> Enter into handleSwatchScrollAction
>
> (deltaX, deltaY) = (0.0, 40.0)
>
> diffFactor is: 1.005
>
> finish handleSwatchScrollAction

So, why from the view there is no change from the second time to do zoom out(scroll up) operation?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Don't you just end up setting the scaleX and scaleY to the same value each time?

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand exactly. I guess, you mean whether I set the same value, I think so. And the first time it works well, I think this means I set the right value.

Comment: First time you scroll, you effectively call `setScaleX(1.005);`, so it zooms by 0.5% or so. Second time you scroll, you call `setScaleX(1.005);` again; since this is already the value of `scaleX` it won't change anything.

Comment: Thank you so much!My understanding before is not right. Shame on me. Wish you have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just setting the scale values to the same value (1.005) every time you scroll. The first time, you will see a zoom of 0.5% or so; but on subsequent scroll events you are not changing the value.

You need something like:

```
double diffFactor = ... // as before
double scale = this.fxSwatch.getScaleX() * diffFactor ;

this.fxSwatch.setScaleX(scale);
this.fxSwatch.setScaleY(scale);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. My understanding was wrong. Thanks a lot!Wish you a good day!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that helped clear it up for you. If this answers the question, please mark it as correct (and similarly for your other question).